# Better way to optimize bulk_create when uploading CSV file, with records related to junction model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have the following view:

```
### VIEW ###

def project(request, project_id):
    creator_id = request.user.id

    # Get project
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id, creator_id=creator_id)

    # Get all backers
    all_backers = project.backers.all().distinct()

    # CSV UPLOAD
    csvform = csvUploadForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        csvform = csvUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if csvform.is_valid():
            csvform = csvform.save(commit=False)
            csvform.for_project_id = project_id
            csvform.creator_id = creator_id
            csvform.save()

            # READ CSV
            csv_file = csvform.csv
            
            data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
            io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
            next(io_string)
            
            backers_list = csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        
            objs = [
                Backer(
                    backer_number=row[0],
                    backer_uid=row[1],
                    name=row[2],
                    email=row[3],
                    shipping_country=row[4],
                    shipping_amount=row[5],
                    reward_title=row[6],
                    backing_minimum=row[7],
                    reward_id=row[8],
                    pledge_amount=row[9],
                    rewards_sent=row[10],
                    pledged_status=row[11],
                    notes=row[12],
                    pid=project_id
                )
                for row in backers_list
            ]
            try:
                msg = Backer.objects.bulk_create(objs)
                returnmsg = {"status_code": 200}
                print('imported successfully')
            except Exception as e:
                print('Error While Importing Data: ',e)
                returnmsg = {"status_code": 500}


            # Add backer_id and project_id in Backed 
            new_backers = Backer.objects.filter(pid=project_id)

            backed_ids = [
                Backed(
                    backer_id=bid.id,
                    project_id=project_id
                )
                for bid in new_backers
            ]
            try:
                msg = Backed.objects.bulk_create(backed_ids)
                returnmsg = {"status_code": 200}
                print('imported successfully')
            except Exception as e:
                print('Error While Importing Data: ',e)
                returnmsg = {"status_code": 500}

            return redirect('project', project_id=project_id)
    else:
        csvform = csvUploadForm()


...
```

Through this view I am uploading a CSV file, creating a list of it and using bulk_create to push it to model (Backer), in order to speed up the process if there are many records. However, in order for my entire code to work properly in the current state, I need to use junction model (Backed).

Everything is working as intended so far; after uploading the csv records to model with bulk_create (it takes around 2 seconds to process the entire list of around 3500 rows with 15 columns), I am using the same approach to make the relations in the junction model. However, when I add this second part for junction model, the time of processing increase to around 10 seconds for this many records.

I am relatively new to Django and I am not sure if this is normal processing time for 3500 rows. Is there anything you can suggest in order to optimize this mechanic?
Here are the models for this particular function:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    backers = models.ManyToManyField(to='backers.Backer', through='backers.Backed', related_name="backers")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to=upload_to, processors=[SmartResize(290, 290)], format='JPEG', options={'quality': 100}, null=True, blank=True)
    funding = models.IntegerField()
    goal = models.IntegerField()
    backers_count = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    started = models.DateField()
    ended = models.DateField()
    created_on = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Backer(models.Model):
    pid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    backer_number = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=True, null=True)
    backer_uid = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_amount = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    reward_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    backing_minimum = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    reward_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    pledge_amount = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    pledged_at = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    rewards_sent = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    pledged_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)

class Backed(models.Model):
    backer = models.ForeignKey(Backer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="backedbacker")
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="backedproject")
```

Let me know if you need some additional information. Any hints would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `new_backers = Backer.objects.filter(pid=project_id)` are only *new* `Backer`s? Since the `Project` already exists, there can be records that already exist.

Comment: That's just generic name in this case. Just something that sounds logical to me. But anyway that variable can be called anything. The backers that are created through csv file and pushed to model for a particular project prior to calling new_backers, are in the same table with many more backers from different projects. So for the second bulk_create for Backed mode, I am filtering only the backers for this particular project.

All of this works fine, just I am not sure if 10 seconds of processing time is okay for only 3500 rows of records and if this can be optimized in more neat way.

Comment: but if you import twice for the same `project_id`, that thus means that `new_backers` will not contain 3'500 records, but 7'000 records... The ones you added here, and the ones that already existed. You will also make *duplicated* `Backer` records: for the items that already existed.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what is the issue you are pointing to. This code works fine so far without making duplicates in Backer model. With the first bulk_create, I am creating records from the uploaded csv file. Beside the info from that csv file, i have added pid for each added backer (each row in Backer) that is equal to the project_id for this particular project for which I am uploading the csv file. Afterwards I am filtering the entire Backer table based on 'pid' to select the backers only for this particular project. The second bulk_create is based only on these filtered backers..

Comment: for this particular project, and this second bulk_create is adding the required information to the junction model called Backed. It is junction model that connects Project model and Backers model, and it is required for proper function of some of the code that follows up in the view for other parts of the functionality